# Open file with mmap fails

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, mmap

Python 2.7 on Windows. Trying to use mmap module, but use open file handler instead of `with open(filename, "r+b") as f:` I just open it and get an `WindowsError [Error 5]`.

It does reproduce, either run as Administrator or not.
Using `codecs.open()` doesn't resolve the problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import mmap

class QSHFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file = open(filename, 'r')
        self.fileno = self.file.fileno()
        self.mm = mmap.mmap(self.fileno, 0)
        print(self.mm[:5])  # prints first 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qsh = QSHFile('example.qsh')
```

After a bit or research, I came into:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap

class QSHFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file = open(filename, 'rb')
        self.fileno = self.file.fileno()
        self.mm = mmap(self.fileno, 0, access=ACCESS_READ)
        print(self.mm[:5])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qsh = QSHFile('example.qsh')
```

And now it's working fine. Am I doing correct now?

Comment: Why did you open the file in text mode?

Comment: open cmd as an administrator, then call your python script from there

Comment: or provide an absolute filename!

Comment: from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap
...
self.file = open(filename, 'rb')
...
self.mm = mmap(self.fileno, 0, access=ACCESS_READ)

helped, testing now

Comment: also make sure no other programs currently are using the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, that's it, thanks to everyone!**

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap
from binascii import hexlify as hex

class QSHFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file = open(filename, 'rb')
        print('File [%s] opened' % self.filename)
        self.fileno = self.file.fileno()
        self.mm = mmap(self.fileno, 0, access=ACCESS_READ)
        print('File size: %s bytes' % self.mm.size())
        print(hex(self.mm[:5]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qsh = QSHFile('example.qsh')
```

Comment: The [documention](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) says that, on Windows, if you don't specify `access` it defaults to `ACCESS_WRITE`. The point being that your "correct way to do it" depends entirely on what you want (something you never really specified in your question).